# How do I targert child Woocommerce Categories with pre_get_posts

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I have created an online store that sales E-books and E-magazines, for books I have a "ebooks" product category with child categories and for the magazines I have a "emagazines" category with child categories like "women", "men" and "business". For the emagazines I have created a pre_get_posts function that is meant to modify the queries on the entire magazines section of my store. Here is the code I have

```
        function magazine_filter($query) {
            if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->query_vars['product_cat'] ==  'emagazines' :

                 // My code goes here

            endif ;
        }

        add_action('pre_get_posts','magazine_filter');
```

The problem is that after I target the "emagazines" category, my function only affects the eMagazines category and not the children categories like "Women", "Men", "Business" etc. The obvious solution would be to manually target all my subcategories as well but this is loooong. I want this to be dynamic so that this function always targets any children categories of the "eMagazines" category as they are created.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is untested, but something like this should work. This first grabs the term you're looking for by its slug (for easier identification), and then grabs all terms that are a descendant of the target term. I can't remember if the original parent term is returned as a result in the query, so if it isn't, uncomment the line after the term query:

```
function magazine_filter($query) {
    $emag = get_term_by('slug', 'emagazines', 'product_cat');
    $tree = get_terms('product_cat', array(
        'fields'=>'ids', //Should be 'ids' not 'id'
        'hide_empty'=>false,
        'child_of'=>$emag->term_id
    ));
    //$tree[] = $emag->term_id; //Uncomment this if the emagazines term ID isn't included.
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && in_array($query->query_vars['product_cat'], $tree) ) :

             // My code goes here

    endif ;
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','magazine_filter');
```

**EDIT:** Here's the documentation on [get_terms](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms). I originally had the 'fields' argument set as `'id'` instead of `'ids'` which was causing problems.

I don't know what `$query->query_vars['product_cat']` returns, but if it's the term slug, consider changing to:

```
$tree = get_terms('product_cat', array(
    'fields'=>'id=>slug',
    'hide_empty'=>false,
    'child_of'=>$emag->term_id
));
//$tree[$emag->term_id] = $emag->slug; //Uncomment this if the emagazines term slug isn't included.
```

Comment: Consider changing `'id'` to `slug` if `$query->query_vars['product_cat']` is referencing the category by its slug.

Comment: Does get_terms() work in pre_get_posts? $tree is returning what seems to be an empty array if it's possible. I change 'id' to 'slug'

Comment: I was taking a guess at what your taxonomy is actually called. Is it registered as 'product_cat'? Or something else?

Comment: yes it's a woocommerce product category with the term slug 'emagazines', $emag is returning the correct values so that oart works, it's $tree that seems empty.

Comment: What do you get if you call `$tree = get_terms('product_cat');`?

Comment: I see what you mean, the taxonomy is in fact registered as product_cat (Woocommerce product category) I'm pulling my hair, this is confusing.

Comment: It's ok, I realized the taxonomy was correct when you said that `$emag` was returning the correct value. We're very close, just need to fine-tune it. Please see my last comment, and see what you get by calling `$tree = get_terms('product_cat');`

Comment: OK Thank you so much for your help so far! 'ids' finally works, it returns all 'ids' excluding the parent but 'id=>slug' doesn't unless I comment out  'child_of'. I am so close!

Comment: Finally it worked, I have updated your answer with the solution. Thank you

Comment: Glad you got it! Hopefully this will help others in the future.